# How to empty REQUEST array?

Tags: php, security

For my framework, i want to empty/disable REQUEST array for security reasons and users should only use proper arrays such as POST, GET or COOKIE. But i don't know how to do it. Even something like below doesn't seem to work, it empties even GET POST, etc.

```
$temp_get = $_GET;
$temp_post = $_POST;
$temp_cookie = $_COOKIE;
// empty request array
$_REQUEST = array();
$_GET = $temp_get;
$_POST = $temp_post;
$_COOKIE = $temp_cookie;
```

Comment: Are people just that dumb? I don't think so and $_REQUEST is useful in certain scenarious. You're wasting extra CPU time that brings no value whatsoever, by the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do here is to replace all those functions/variables using $_REQUEST with their correct method. Stick to conventions, GET to pull, POST to insert data, and don't forget $_COOKIE.

If you do not take input from $_REQUEST you will save yourself a lot of trouble. To always be safe just remember to escape any kind of input that might be tampered (_GET,*POST*,_COOKIE, and don't forget some of those nasty _SERVER variables).

Comment: could not get your dear, it seems i was not looking for this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing

```
unset($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: it is of no use, it will empty everything even get post and cookie

Comment: um, no. $_REQUEST is a separate array from $_GET. Did you even test this?

Answer (score 1):

Would a solution like this work?

```
<?php

class Request
{
    public static $get, $post, $cookie;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$get = $_GET;
        self::$post = $_POST;
        self::$cookie = $_COOKIE;
    }
}

new Request();
$_REQUEST = array();
print_r(Request::$get);
```

You can test it by going to test.php?a=b&c=d

Comment: this actually helped me understand them better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you loop through `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, saving their data, then clearing `$_REQUEST`?

```
$tget = array();
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v)
{
    $tget[$k] = $v;
}

$tpost = array();
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    $tpost[$k] = $v;
}

$tcookie = array();
foreach($_COOKIE as $k=>$v)
{
    $tcookie[$k] = $v;
}

unset($_REQUEST);

$_GET = $tget;
$_POST = $tpost;
$_COOKIE = $tcookie;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the new variables aren't inherently global in scope.